# Dynamically load user32.dll from R & call external function

Tags: r, dllimport

I try to access user32.dll  functions in R Session. I used the code:

```
dyn.load("c://windows//system32//user32.dll")
.External("MessageBeep", 0L)
```

But R session crashes. According to documentation `.External` is intended to use during R package creation. However there was no prohibition to use it as shown above.

I am using Windows 8 and RStudio (1.1.453) / R (3.5.0). Could you advise a proper way to call external Windows functions from R session?

Comment: Where do you specify the calling convention as stdcall? My guess is you can't and would need to create a wrapper dll.

Comment: As I understand calling conventions should be specified during compilation. And I should look either 1) to compile some package or 2) to use some external process to access to desired dll (somethin like VBA)?

Comment: The calling convention of that function is stdcall. I'm not sure if R can call stdcall functions. I think it always uses cdecl. VBA isn't what you need. Which functions are you actually trying to call?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I found SO post on [cdecl & stdcall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404372/stdcall-and-cdecl) as well as more thoroughly try to read the R package creation documentation. I am trying to call any function from any dll function. For academic purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the Win32 C API, thus you can load the user32.dll, and then use the `Foreign` `{base}` `.C()` call too access the Window32 [MessageBeep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebeep) function.

##Example Code

```
dyn.load("c://windows//system32//user32.dll")
.C("MessageBeep")
```

##Runtime Output

```
> dyn.load("c://windows//system32//user32.dll")
> .C("MessageBeep")
list()
>
```

You should hear the Windows Message "Beep" - Alas, I have yet to figure out how to include sounds in solutions (chuckle).

Note: I'd also recommend you take a look at the [Rcpp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) package, I am a big fan.