# According to C convention, is it the responsibility of the callee function to return a given type or the caller function?

Tags: c

Assume this code snippet:

```
int test(int input){
  // using asm() manually populate the `return register` with `input` and return.
}

int main(){
 return test(-1);
}
```

Assume we write our own assembly code to populate the `return register` under `test`.
The 64 bit `return register` is set to `-1 sign extended to 64 bits` which is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` but the return type is a 32 bit int (i.e the expected value in register should be `0xFFFFFFFF`).

My question is, according to C, is it the responsibility of `test()` to return the correct
value in the register OR is it the responsibility of callee (`main` in this case) to cast the returned value correctly and truncate it if needed?

Or in other words, is `test` supposed to make sure the register value is set to `0xFFFFFFFF` and not `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` before returning?

Comment: This isn't standardized. There's two common calling conversions for PC, "cdecl" and "stdcall". See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404372/stdcall-and-cdecl/3404412. For other systems, it is wildly implementation-defined. In embedded systems it can vary from compiler to compiler even.

Comment: My two cents: If you define `test` as returning an `int`, then its _implementation defined_ as the C standard only requires `int` to be at least 16 bits, therefore you should set the return register **accordingly to the implementation**.  If you've specified `int32_t` _(stdint.h)_ as a return type, writing the whole 64 bits return register would have been wrong as it will be unexpected by the compiler (until you 've told it you're doing that). Here, i only see an `int` at each level, so there should never be any cast required.

Comment: Yes, you have to look to your platform's calling conventions / ABI (you haven't said what your platform is).  It will give the precise rules for returning values of every possible type.  For `int`, it will state which register the value should be in, and if that register is larger than the size of an `int`, it will specify whether sign or zero extension is required.

Comment: Note that many common 64-bit machines actually provide 32-bit architectural registers as the low half of a 64-bit register.  For instance, on x86-64 under most common conventions, you return an `int` in the 32-bit register `eax`, which is the low half of the 64-bit register `rax`.  The upper half of `rax` is to be ignored by the caller, so it is not necessary to sign extend (but it is harmless if you do).