Stack corruption around a HandleScope in v8
I get a: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'handle_scope' was corrupted.
when I run this code:
#include <iostream>

#define V8_COMPRESS_POINTERS 1

#include <V8/v8.h>
#include <V8/libplatform/libplatform.h>

namespace consoleUtils {
    static void log(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
        v8::Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
        if (args.Length() > 0) {
            v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, args[0]);
            std::cout << *utf8 << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

class Console {
    v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> logTemplate;
public:
    Console(v8::Isolate* isolate, v8::Local<v8::Context> context) {
        v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> logFuncTemplate = v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, consoleUtils::log);
        logTemplate.Reset(isolate, logFuncTemplate);
        context->Global()->Set(context, v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "log").ToLocalChecked(), logFuncTemplate->GetFunction(context).ToLocalChecked()).Check();
    }

    ~Console() {
        logTemplate.Reset();
    }
};

class Engine {
private:
    v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    v8::Persistent<v8::Context> context;
    std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform;

public:
    v8::Isolate* isolate = nullptr;
    Console* console = nullptr;

    Engine() {
        // Initialize V8.
        v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation("./v8-data");
        v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData("./v8-data");
        platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
        v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
        v8::V8::Initialize();

        // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
        create_params.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
        isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);

        // Create a new context.
        v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
        v8::Local<v8::Context> local_context = v8::Context::New(isolate);
        context.Reset(isolate, local_context);

        // Initialize console with the current context.
        console = new Console(isolate, local_context);
    }

    ~Engine() {
        delete console;
        context.Reset();
        isolate->Dispose();
        v8::V8::Dispose();
        delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
    }

    void runExample() {
        v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
        v8::Local<v8::Context> local_context = context.Get(isolate);
        v8::Context::Scope context_scope(local_context);

        v8::Local<v8::String> source = v8::String::NewFromUtf8Literal(isolate, "log('Hello, World!')");
        v8::Local<v8::Script> script = v8::Script::Compile(local_context, source).ToLocalChecked();
        v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(local_context).ToLocalChecked();

        v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result);
        std::cout << *utf8 << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Engine* engine = new Engine();
    engine->runExample();
    delete engine;
    return 0;
}

my v8 build settings (args.gn) are:

is_debug = true
target_cpu = "x64"
v8_enable_backtrace = true
v8_enable_slow_dchecks = true
v8_optimized_debug = false
is_component_build = false
v8_static_library = true
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
use_custom_libcxx = false
is_clang = false

# Disable WebAssembly
v8_enable_webassembly = false
v8_enable_wasm_simd256 = false

v8_enable_pointer_compression = true

v8_enable_sandbox = false

enable_iterator_debugging = true


The IDE I use is Microsoft Visual Studio, I compile the code using MSVC. the standard is C++ 20.
I have tried debugging myself, but sadly I lack the experience to do so. Needless to say it didn't result in much but my own frustration.
Edit: I have tried reinstalling visual studio, and rebuilding v8.
this code produces the error!
also managing the Engine by pointer is because it's going to be a big class, so I don't want to overflow the stack.

MIght not be related... but last time (long ago) I saw this error it was because of a mismatch in calling convention. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404372/stdcall-and-cdecl) between different libraries.

I don't believe that this is it, because this error also occurs in a hello world example.

Please clarify last comment. You cannot even successfully write/compile/run a simple Hello World program with your build tools?

This is a hint your visual studio installation is not working correctly. Also if you're using visual studio, manage your depenendencies on v8 using vcpkg (https://vcpkgx.com/details.html?package=v8)

should I reinstall visual studio? @PepijnKramer

I can compile, but get a runtime error @user4581301

If you are asking about an error produced from "Hello world", why are you showing us this "HandleScope in v8" code?

In agreement with Drew. If you have the identical problem running a hello world program, just show that. But it has to be identical. And if you do, it sure sounds like tools. The problem with reinstalling without understanding the problem you encountered is odds are extremely high that you'll follow the same chain of events and wind up with the same result. The problem: It's next-to-impossible to troubleshoot IDE problems over the Internet. Often the only way you figure out what needs to be in the question to make it answerable is to have already solved the problem.

But there are a few things you can do to help us help you narrow down the problem. To start with, were you ever able to run programs you compiled? ie. is this a new problem?

If hello world isn't working then I think it must some kind of version conflict, between say the CRT used to compile and the CRT actually loaded at runtime. I have to echo what's been said already, if hello world isn't working why did you lead with all this v8 stuff?

Off topic, but why this:Engine* engine = new Engine(); engine->runExample(); delete engine; instead of simply Engine engine; engine.runExample();?  Your code has all the earmarks of a non-C++ programmer (maybe Python or Java programmer?) trying to write C++.

@user4581301 this is a new problem, i was able to run stuff just fine.

@PaulMcKenzie i just forgot to add it. out of curiosity, what are the earmarks?

The earmarks are using new to create objects when not necessary.  A C++ programmer can always tell that someone from another programming language is writing C++, just on that one issue alone.

@DrewDormann this code produces the same error. I never said I was talking about the hello world example. I just said that I have already tried minimal code, which caused the same error.

@PaulMcKenzie the choice of stack allocation or heap allocation is arbitrary in this example. I know that stack is faster.

@john other programs compile fine. the hello world I meant was the v8 example from their page :)

@BLAD231353 OK, that distinction was lost on me.

OK. We need to nuke most of these comments to prevent future confusion. On your end, see how much you can remove from this code example without removing the bug. Use [mre] for inspiration. Hopefully you aren't fighting with DLL Hell, some other version of the V8 libraries lurking earlier in the system path.
